# Laravel (newbie) - Failed to load autoload.php

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel

When I created the local project via composer I ran my application with no problems.

Now I deployed my application and tried to hit the entry point ("/"), and it works: it performs the expected redirect to /home.

BUT /home is the problem: I get (in production) an empty (blank) response, and the error log shows:

> [24-Feb-2014 20:14:11] PHP Fatal error:  require() [function.require]: Failed opening required `'__DIR__/../bootstrap/autoload.php'` (include_path=`'.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/share/pear'`) in `/home1/centrau9/public_html/index.php` on line 21

Note: the file exists, and permissions of /bootstrap/ are 0755, and permissions for autoload.php are 0644. The framework is www-unreachable (i.e. the public_html corresponds to the "public" directory of the laravel project).

The routes.php file is as follows:

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the Closure to execute when that URI is requested.
|
*/

define('STATIC_URL', '/static/');

Route::get('/', function()
{
    return Redirect::route('home');
});

Route::get('home', array('as' => 'home', function()
{
    return Response::make(
        View::make('home_html'), 200,
        array('Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
    );
}));

Route::get('nosotros', array('as' => 'nosotros', function()
{
    return Response::make(
        View::make('nosotros_html'), 200,
        array('Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
    );
}));

Route::get('modelos/{clase}/{modelo}', array('as' => 'modelos', function($clase, $modelo)
{
    $modelos = CentralCarController::datosModelos();
    if (!isset($modelos[$clase]))
    {
        App::abort(404, 'No se puede encontrar la página');
    }
    $datosModelo = null;
    foreach($modelos[$clase] as $modelo_)
    {
        if ($modelo_['name'] == $modelo)
        {
            $datosModelo = $modelo_;
        }
    }
    if (!$datosModelo)
    {
        App::abort(404, 'No se puede encontrar la página');
    }

    return Response::make(
        View::make('modelos_html', array('model_class' => json_encode($clase), 'model_name' => json_encode($modelo))), 200,
        array('Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
    );
}))->where(array('clase' => '[\w-]+', 'modelo' => '[\d\w-]+'));

Route::get('posventa', array('as' => 'posventa', function()
{
    return Response::make(
        View::make('posventa_html'), 200,
        array('Content-Type' => 'text/html; charset=utf-8')
    );
}));

Route::match(array('GET', 'POST'), 'contacto', array('as' => 'contacto', 'uses' => 'CentralCarController@contactoConsulta'));
Route::match(array('GET', 'POST'), 'contacto-cotizar', array('as' => 'contacto-cotizar', 'uses' => 'CentralCarController@contactoCotizar'));
Route::match(array('GET', 'POST'), 'contacto-cita', array('as' => 'contacto-cita', 'uses' => 'CentralCarController@contactoTaller'));
Route::get('contacts-export/{periodo?}', array('as' => 'exportar', 'uses' => 'CentralCarController@exportar'))->where(array('periodo' => '[DWMY]|6M'));
Route::get('models-data', array('as' => 'models-data', 'uses' => 'CentralCarController@modelos'));
Route::get('busqueda', array('as' => 'busqueda', 'uses' => 'CentralCarController@busqueda'));
```

AND the .htaccess file in public_html is as follows:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes...
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"the public_html corresponds to the "public" directory of the laravel project"*? What does *"corresponds"* mean in this context?

Comment: You have moved your index.php into root it should be in public dir.
If you are using it in the root then use `__DIR__/bootstrap/autoload.php`.

Comment: @AmitGarg The error message says `index.php` is in `/home1/centrau9/public_html/`. OP, what does line 21 of `index.php` look like

Comment: @Phil yes! I have seen that.

Comment: @AmitGarg line 21: require \_\_DIR\_\_.'/../bootstrap/autoload.php';

Comment: @Phil the siblings of public_html were siblings of public. the children (content) of public_html were  children of public.

Comment: Got the bitter answer: __DIR__ does not exist. Reason: wrong php version. I need a way to upgrade it now, but it's a shared hosting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably running PHP 5.2. Check your PHP version. You need > 5.3

Comment: PHP >= 5.3.7 to be precise

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: wrong php version (5.2.x).